# Rotating blocks in 2D-array

Tags: java, rotation, coordinate-systems

I am making a program similar to the famous game Tetris and I've run into some problems when it comes to rotating a block.

I know you are able to rotate figures in a coordinate system by using "x = -y" and "y = x" but the problem is that because I am using an array of integers to represent the block it makes things so much more difficult.

My array looks like:

```
int[][] space = new int[20][10];
```

And if a coordinate contains a block the value is 1 else it's 0.

So how can I rotate a block in that space without getting trouble with negative numbers?

Comment: If the values are either 0 or 1, why not just use booleans?

Comment: The best way to figure it out is if you grab a pencil and a piece of paper and draw a grid and a shape within it, then observe what happens when you rotate it. I know this isn't an answer but trust me, you'll learn a lot more this way.

Comment: Since you are using a 2D array, I think it would be easier for you to use a square matrix for this purpose. This is because, in a square matrix you will not have the problem of interchanging the size of rows/columns if required while rotations.

Comment: @biziclop I took your advice and was thinking that maybe it will be easier if I add the shape I want to rotate to a new smaller array so I can set an offset much easier and rotate it that way. I will try it out but not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample piece (reusing your *int[][]* using 0's and 1's, which might as well be done using a boolean array):

```
private static final int[][] piece = new int[][] {
        { 0, 1, 0, },
        { 1, 1, 1, },
};
```

You can rotate a piece doing this:

```
private static int[][] rotate( final int[][] piece ) {
    final int[][] res = new int[piece[0].length][piece.length];
    for (int x = 0; x < piece.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < piece[0].length; y++) {
            res[(res.length-1)-y][x] = piece[x][y];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The starting piece:

```
010
111
```

Here's *rotate(piece)*:

```
01
11
01
```

Here's *rotate(rotate(piece))*:

```
111
010
```

And here's *rotate(rotate(rotate(piece)))*:

```
10
11
10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood this correctly, you can do this by applying a fixed offset to the coordinates. The offset is the center around which you want to rotate.

```
int oldSpace[][] = new int[20][10];
int newSpace[][] = new int[20][10];
int offX = 10;
int offY = 5;
for(int x = -5; x < 5; x++) {
  for(int y = -5; y < 5; y++) {
    newSpace[offX+x][offY+y] = oldSpace[offX-y][offY+x];
  }
}
```

I assumed 20 was the X dimension and 10 the Y dimension. This rotates a 10x10 block around the coordinate (10,5). Note that I've only rotated a 10x10 block in the middle as that's the overlap between the two spaces. Perhaps you are copying a [20][10] array to a [10][20] array, and in that case you can increase the range of y so it runs from -10 to 9.

EDIT: Sorry, you also need a different set of offsets if you have a different shaped output array, as (10,5) will no longer be in the center. But you should be able to figure this out.